# Full-width slider in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple jquery mobile site that includes a few buttons and a slider.  The buttons stretch out to fill the whole horizontal space, but the slider does not.  It feels very clunky.  Is there any way to coax a jquery-mobile slider to fill the whole horizontal space?

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
    <div data-role="content" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
        <form>
           <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider-0" value="50" min="0" max="100"/>
        </form>
       <a id="button-1" href="#" data-role="button">Button</a>
       <a id="button-2" href="#" data-role="button">Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Side note: this code includes two divs with data-role="content".  Is that going to get me into trouble?  jquery-mobile doesn't like to put sliders into footers, but I need the slider to act like a footer with fixed position at the bottom of the display area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are targeting a consistent screen size this would be pretty easy. By default in  JQM 1.1RC2 I see them using 65% for the slider bar. The input field before the slider however is fixed at 50px. Try playing with .ui-slider width to get a closer value just be careful because it will look different depending on the screen size.

`div.ui-slider{width:80%;}`

Maybe something like 80% will work better for you. As for your second part I have no idea test it out and let us know.

Comment: Thanks!  The second part seems to work okay on chrome, ffox, and kindle.  I haven't got around to testing it elsewhere yet.